# Como fazer uma média de uma curva?

Tags: matlab

Estou tirando uma curva de temperatura com um LM35 porém não consigo obter uma média da curva da temperatura para realizar meus calculos. Segue uma imagem de minha curva:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: esse plot me parece ser um vetor não é? qual a dificuldade de somar e multiplicar pelo tamanho do vetor ?? tem algum código ?

Answer (score 0):

Talvez a sua pergunta seja como fazer o ajuste dos pontos a uma curva. Se assim for pode usar a [funcao polyfit](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/polyfit.html):

p = polyfit(x,y,n) devolve os coeficientes do polinomio de grau n que melhor se ajusta aos dados

Aqui esta um exemplo para um ajuste a um polinomio de grau 2

```
% gerando dados aleatorios para x e y
x = linspace(0,100,100)
y = x.^2+3*x+2
y = y + randn(size(y))*500

% aproximando os dados a um polinomio de grau 2
p = polyfit(x,y,2) 
eq1 = strcat('y = ', num2str(p(1)),'x^2 + ',num2str(p(2)),'x + ',num2str(p(3)))

% mostra resultados na figura
figure(1)
hold on
plot (x,y,'+') % dados originais
text (max(x)/4,max(y)*5/6,eq1) % mostra a equacao no grafico
fitted_curve = p(1)*x.^2+p(2)*x+p(3) % cria curva ajustada para mostrar no grafico
plot (x,fitted_curve,'r') % mostra curva ajustada a vermelho no grafico
```

Comment: E o perguntador some ...